# Loading 50 dynamic Angular Components in *NgFor takes long time to initialize (15 secs)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-dynamic-components

I am loading 50 angular components in a ngFor loop
formItemList is a array and has 50 angular components

```
<mat-expansion-panel expanded="true" *ngFor="let item of formItemList; let i = index" id="{{item.id}}"
                class="pad-top-sm, expansion-panel">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header id="{{'mat-header' + i}}">
                    <div>
                        <a id="{{'mat-help' + i}}" href="{{ item.help }}" class="inline" title="help"
                            target="_blank">
                            <s-icon name="help-circle" class="relative active small margin-right-xs">
                            </s-icon>
                        </a>
                        <h3 id="{{'mat-expansion-label' + i}}" class="inline">{{ item.label }}</h3>
                    </div>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <ng-container app-add-component [component]="item.component"></ng-container>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

```
static formItemList: FormItem[] = [
    {
      id: "testId",
      label: "testId",
      help: "https://google.com",
      component: FormComponent
    }];  // has 50 such objects
```

Form Component has no server calls and UI html is an empty html table.
***app-add-component*** is a directive that creates components

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[app-add-component]',
})
export class AddComponentDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() component: Type<any> | undefined;
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
            if (this.component)
                this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.component);

    }
}
```

This is working but takes almost more than 15 sec to bind the components to the HTML. The scrren is frozen for that time.
How can I make this load faster?

I have tried trackby in ngFor but I am supplying all the 50 components all at once so this is of no use.

The use case is for all the 50 components should load in under 5 secs

Comment: I think you have 2 problems: (1) you don't have a `trackBy` in your form, (2) you have lots of components in you list, and the creation of each is expensive. I suspect that if you add a simple `console.log` in the constructor of the directive you will see thousands of calls instead of just 50.

Comment: Unrelated: usually you don't  need to set `id` attributes when working in angular. It's perfectly useless.

Comment: do you have a stackblitz for this?

Comment: I tried using the trackBy but saw no improvement what so ever.

Comment: @ShashankDhasal you have an incomplete example, that no one can see. We cannot guess blindly. How are the components loaded? Are they all of the same type? If you can provide a Stackblitz I think we can try to help you, but currently I can't see any obvious problem, besided the one I indicated you. And you didn't bother to confirm that you are currrently creating 50 components, with the trackBy applied.